# PL SQL trigger not functioning

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

please help me with the with the following trigger:

```
    create or replace TRIGGER "TRG_ECO"
AFTER delete OR UPDATE or INSERT ON add_tree

  referencing new as new old as old
  for each row
  declare
  var_num  number(1) :=1; 
  var_tree_type number(1);


BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('tRIGGER ADD CONTACT TRRIGGERED: ');



   select tree_type 
          INTO var_tree_type
          FROM master
          where seq_id = :old.add_parent;
    dbms_output.put_line('tRIGGER TRRIGGERED: ' || :new.add_parent);
   if(var_tree_type=7) then 


        select 
               CASE
                    WHEN (:new.add_parent not in (select a.seq_id  
                    from mastera)) then 0
                    WHEN (:new.add_parent in (select a.seq_id  
                    from mastera)) then 1
                    ELSE 1

            end
        into var_num
        from dual;


          UPDATE masterSET contact = var_num where seq_id = :new.add_parent;

    end if;


    dbms_output.put_line('tRIGGER TRRIGGERED: ');

END TRG_ECO;
```

because when i try to delete, insert, update a row  i get an error like:

> Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-01403: no data found
>   ORA-06512: at "TOADM.TRG_ECO", line 11
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TOADM.TRG_ECO'
>   01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
>   *Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
>   *Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
>   Elapsed: 00:00:00.032

When i update the code with

```
create or replace TRIGGER "TRG_ECO"
AFTER UPDATE or INSERT ON add_tree
```

and I put where `seq_id = :new.add_parent;` I get the error:

```
"SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'TOADM.ECO' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger."
```

Comment: `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception needs to be handled. When a `select into` statement  returns no rows `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception is raise. Error message says it all. Second `select` statement looks redundant. The result of the `case` expression can be assigned directly to a `var_num` variable.

Comment: But I have data to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When triggered by a delete statement there are no :new values, likewise when triggered by an insert statement there are no :old values. This may be a problem here.

Comment: select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'TRG_FIRST_CONTACT_FROM_ADD' <-- to see what error the trigger actually gets

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF"

Comment: SEQUENCE 1 LINE 24 POSITION 4

Comment: I think now it works. Thank you :-). The error above was raised when I tried to catch exception like Nicholas Krasnov said.